# Can I display a random string into a HTML document?

Tags: string, html, random

I have a web page. I'd like you randomly switch between two different strings. What is the easiest way of doing this?

```
<!-- BEGIN #random part -->
  <section id="countdown">
   <div class="countdown-background">
    <h1>This is the first random string</h1>
    <h1>I'd like this to be the second random string</h1>
   </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="countdown-background">
   <p>Here's another first random string</p>
   <p>And here's the second of the second random string</p>
  </div>   
 </section>
<!-- END #random part -->
```

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Comment: Use JS/jQuery. HTML is static.

Answer (score 1):

of course you could try using javascript.

```
<body>
<p id="pp">

</p>



<script>
var strarray = new Array("Random string1","Random string2","Random string3");

randomnum = Math.round(Math.random()*2);
para = document.getElementbyId('pp');

para.innerHTML = strarray[randomnum]

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: How will Google react on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no randomization in HTML. You would need to do this with client-side scripting (JavaScript, in practice), or with server-side scripting (e.g., PHP). The choice depends on the availability of server-side techniques and on the purpose. Specifically, do you want Google to “see” both strings, or randomly one of them, or neither of them? After deciding on this, the rest is relatively easy: just use the randomization functions(s) of the programming language chosen.